# For which $\alpha$ does this function belongs to $L_p(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: lp-spaces, characteristic-functions

given $M=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n | \|x\|_2 \ge 1  \}$, $\alpha >0$

For which values of p is 
$$
     f_{\alpha}(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} \frac{1}{\|x\|_2^{\alpha}}, & x\in M \\
         0, & x\not\in M\end{array}\right. .
  $$
a member of $L_p(\mathbb{R}^n)?$

I thought if I transform this problem into spherical coordiantes, the problem boils down to show that $\int_1^{\infty} (f_{\alpha}(r)r^n)^p dr$ is bounded. But I think thats not the case for any p. Is this correct or am I mistaken?

Greetings.

Comment: That should be $$\int_1^\infty r^{-\alpha p} \cdot r^n~dr$$